# Can I attach objects to QListWidgetItems in PyQt?

Tags: qt, object, pyqt, qlistwidget

Is it possible to set/get a object for an item in a QListWidget the same way you set/get the text of the item?

Comment: Do you mean you want to associate an object with each line of text? You'd probably be better using the model-view framework if you want to do this, or just associate the text with a python dict, perhaps stored in the QListWidget object itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [QListWidgetItem.setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#setData):

```
item = QListWidgetItem('Text', parent)
data = ('foo', 'bar', [1, 2, 3])
item.setData(Qt.UserRole, data)
...
# QVariant version 1 API (python2 default)
print item.data(Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()
# QVariant version 2 API (python3 default)
print item.data(Qt.UserRole)
```